# What is the convenient way to take a screenshot and share it to Google+?

Tags: screenshot, google-plus

What is the convenient way to take a screenshot and share it to Google+?

I tried `Shutter` but it doesn't have a plugin to share to Google+.

I also tried to install Nanoshot, but I got `E: Unable to locate package nanoshot`.

So is there any other methods?

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to cobble together an API plug-in for shutter using the [Google Plus API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/) info.

To fix the unable to locate on nanoshot, you'll need to add the nanoshot ppa.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nanoshot/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nanoshot
```

More information on the installation procedures can be found on the [nanoshot page](http://nanoshot.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Thanks. Hopefully someone else already developed the plugin. :)

Comment: @sirmoo : "if not supported" is not supported on AskUbuntu neither...  ;-)
Evan : please click the little grey check-mark below the number "1" (my up-vote) to accept the answer as that is considered a better "thank you" than actually typing "Thanks" as SirMoo will gain reputation points from you accepting his answer... :-)